# what is the maximum number of workers and concurrency can be configured in celery

Tags: python, celery, celery-task

If I'm scheduling **IO bound task in celery** and if my server spec was like **Quad Core with 8GB RAM,** How many **workers and concurrency I can use.**

If CPU bound processes are advised to use 4 workers and 8 concurrency for Quad Core processor. Whats  the spec for IO bound process.

In my task I will be performing API calls, manipulating the received data and storing the processed data in server.

Answer (score 2):

That's like asking 'how long is a piece of string' and I'm sure there isn't a single simple answer. Certainly it will be more than 8 threads, with a useful upper limit at the maximum concurrent I/O tasks needed, maybe determined by the number of remote users of your service that the I/O tasks are communicating with. Presumably at some number of tasks 'manipulating the data' will start to load up your processor and you won't be i/o bound any more.

Comment: @barny...Yes, that was the problem i faced while reading the documentation. It was literally like the statement you stated 'how long is a piece of string. I am quite sure that my data manipulation will not going to be a bottleneck condition.

Comment: thanks for your reply,,   but can you please suggest it with some accountable count or is there anay proper mathematical calc to obtain this worker count

Comment: Watch the processor loading, make the design flexible so you can increase or decrease the upper limit, and build yourself a test environment which can run some tests with different loads so you know when going live the limits of your implementation... Good luck!